# Regular Expressions PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression

I'm new with Regex in PHP and what I want to know is how to match words that are equal or like each other.

**Example:**

I have the word "designer" and the word "design", if we try to match the designer with design will return false, but if we try to match design with designer it will return a match. I need to match both cases using one preg_match statement.

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Don't use a regex for such a simple use-case. Use string functions and check if the input is equal to "design" or "designer".

Comment: _"if we try to match the designer with design will return false, but if we try to match design with designer it will return a match"_ . Could you please explain that?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the text contains `designed`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for stemming: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming

If you are only looking to match on those two words then do as nickb suggested and keep it simple. If you are seeking to replicate this matching on many words then you could use this PorterStemmer class: http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're looking for is an optional match:

```
/design(?:er)?/
```

The parentheses group the "er", "?:" makes it non-capturing, and the "?" following make that group optional.

In more general terms, if you want to capture a word or any longer version of that word:

```
/design\w*/
```

That matches on "design" and zero or more ("*") word characters ("\w").

Comment: Your suggestion works, but I'm doing this dynamically with PHP, so I need a better approach. I'll try to check what's the biggest string of the two strings and try a match from the small one. Doing this, it has a possibility that the bigger word contains the small word.

Comment: The explanation is not entirely correct. Parentheses group *and*  capture; the following `?` makes the *group* optional, but if it's there, `er` will always be captured. This is a minor nitpick at best, but it explains why `/design(?:er)?/` (using non-capturing parentheses) would be the more logical choice.

Comment: @RafaelFragoso I can only comment on your question. If you provide PHP code as an example we can elaborate on your situation.